# Show data from nested NSMutableArrays and NSDictionarys

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an array filled with dictionaries in a plist:

[image]

The dictionary itself contains an array, keyed by `Taskitler`. I want to show the items in that array in a table view. What should I write to see them? How can I define my data paths?

This code doesnt work:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[mainList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Urun"];
```

Comment: Can you kindly describe your problem please, which you are facing?

Comment: I want to show my Taksitler Array items in my tableview. What should i write to see them ? cell.textLabel.text = [[mainList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Urun"]; this code doesnt work...

Comment: Generally you should "peel the onion" one layer at a time -- start with the array, get the dictionary out of the array, get the inner array out of the dictionary, get the inner dictionary out of the inner array.  Do each on its own line, assigned to a temporary variable.  (This does **not** impact performance.)  Then you can single step through the code and see what's going on.  (Plus it's simply much easier to understand.)

Comment: Hot Licks Thank you !!!! I understand easily with your "peel the onion" logic. I cant vote up your comment because my account is new sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is this. The code below takes advantage of the subscripting syntax in Objective-C.

```
NSArray *root = // root object
NSString *urun = root[0][@"Tasksitler"][0][@"Urun"];
```

Explanation:

`myArray[index]` is equivalent to `[myArray objectAtIndex:index]`.
`myDictionary[@"key"]` is equivalent to `[myDictionary objectForKey:@"key"]`.

You can see which is shorter and easier to understand.

Comment: Your answer is like a gold for me BlackRider. Thank you for that.I can't vote your answer, because my account is new sorry for that. Thank you again. Respects !

Answer (score 1):

You traverse items in an `NSArray` using `objectAtIndex`, and you traverse or seek objects in an `NSDictionary` using `objectForKey`:

```
NSArray *root = // ... root object
NSDictionary *dict = [root objectAtIndex:0]
NSArray *task = [dict objectForKey:@"Tasksitler"];
NSDictionary *taskdict = [task objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *urun = [taskdict objectForKey:@"Urun"];
```